# Why does Emacs always blink when start?

Tags: emacs, editor

I find Emacs always blinks when it startup, My operation system is MacOS 10.14, I take a screenshot to show what I say, and slow the playback to 5%, then I find there is a screen draw first, but it's white fill color, after that it redraws as the config in .emacs file.

Could anybody tell me what's the mechanism of this and how to remove it?

[screenshot of emacs startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ot5yI.gif)

Comment: Presumably because your init.el file loads a different, dark theme, from the default white theme, at startup.

Comment: @mihai, I didn't use init.el file rather than .emacs file as my config. As you suggested, I delete all my config to use an empty file to start. Yes, it stopped blink and keep its initial size unchanged, and the screen is white.

But how can initialize emacs with black-screen, and with the right window size? 

My system is in Dark-mode, Does it matters?

Comment: It is called an `init` file in Emacs world nonetheless, regardless of the fact that your file is `init.el`, `emacs.el`, etc. I'm no Emacs guru, but I would assume that when you start Emacs, it initializes it's windows, buffers, data structures and all that with its default values. Only after this start-up phase does your init file come into play and it configures or changes those default values. This might be the reason you're seeing the default values (white theme) and then your dark theme after init. Mine behaves the same as yours (white then dark), but it doesn't actually bother me.

Comment: Thanks for your patience.
Yes, I understand now. and I want to find some way to change this default behavior, like recompilation, etc.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: You can set most of these in early-init.el with Emacs 27+.  That code gets executed before the GUI comes up.

---

Some Emacs config can happen before `init.el` is loaded, for instance X resources and command line options.  So you can start Emacs like

```
emacs -bg black
```

or edit your ~/.Xresources:

```
Emacs.Background: black
```

and update the xrdb:

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

If you go the X resources route, make sure something updates xrdb at start up/log in.

You can use named colors like in `list-colors-display` or a hex color like `#000000`.